# Javascript parameter

Tags: javascript

I noticed that when I pass a string like this `\[(tan(w)\]` as a parameter to a function, the argument when printed in the function I passed it into is `[(tan(w)]`. Why would the slashes get stripped?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The slash in a string in any language whose syntax is inherited from C is used to escape other characters. For example if you want to put a double quote (`"`) in your string, you use `\"`

To put a slash in a string, you have to put a double slash : `"\\[(tan(w)\\]"`

Comment: JavaScript is a language of the C family?

Comment: @DennisTraub Its syntax, yes, just like java, Go, C#, etc.

Comment: I would say "language with C style syntax".

Comment: It might somewhat look like a C-based language, but that doesn't make it one. In fact I only started to understand JavaScript once I recognized it's not C-based.

Comment: They're just somewhat related syntaxwise.  A lot of the concepts don't translate very well in either direction, but if you know C syntax, it goes a long way toward learning the basic syntax of a bunch of other languages.  The concepts in JS, though, came from a whole different place (Scheme, Self, and a few others not even close in syntax).

Comment: @DennisTraub I edited to make it clearer but it's not uncommon to speak of the C-family languages when speaking of languages whose syntax is inherited from C.

Comment: @DennisTraub I feel that the mindset of thinking "oh I know, that's just like in <langauge>" mostly gets you into trouble. I try to understand the semantics of each language anew without letting other languages cloud my judgement.

Comment: If you talk about syntax, I think all languages has implemented escape character, and they're use same character, the `\`

Comment: @phant0m but it can help you start faster. You probably don't know Go but just looking at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12462377/selecting-a-function-from-a-list-of-functions-in-golang/12462668#12462668) you can get an idea of the structure of the program.

Comment: @dystroy Sure, I agree on that.

Comment: @arufian: Most, but not all.  VB, for example, doubles quotes and (AFAIK) doesn't otherwise use escape characters.  And apparently Delphi uses `#xx` (where `xx` is a numeric character code).

Answer (score 1):

Backslash characters are special.

If you want to pass one in a string, and have it preserved, you have to pass two:

```
"\\[(tan(w)\\]"
```

Answer (score 1):

In a string literal, the `\` has special meaning. It means that you're starting an escape sequence meant to represent some character.

If the escape sequence actually has a specified meaning, the new character is substituted for the entire sequence. If not, the slash is just removed.

The escape sequence to include a literal backslash in the resulting string is a backslash followed by another backslash. `\\`