# How to test a collection of functions by reflection in Go?

Tags: function, unit-testing, reflection, go

I have to write unit tests for several functions with similar signature and return values (an object and an error), which must pass similar test conditions.
I would like to avoid writing:

```go
func TestFunc1(t *testing.T) {
    // tests on return values
}
func TestFunc2(t *testing.T) {
    // tests identical for Func1
}
func TestFunc3(t *testing.T) {
    // tests identical for Func1
}
...
```

(See [this go playground example](http://play.golang.org/p/enAdaVo0HS) for a more complete context)
(yes, go playground doesn't support yet `go test`, only `go run`, and [issue 6511](https://code.google.com/p/go/issues/detail?id=6511) is there to request that feature)

**How would you use reflection ([`reflect` package](http://golang.org/pkg/reflect)) in order to write only one test which would:**

- **call each function in turn?**
- **test their return value?**

I have seen:

- "[How to properly use `.Call` in reflect package, Golang?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20714939/6309)", using [Value.Call](http://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.Call)
- "[Selecting a function from a list of functions in Golang](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12462377/6309)"

But I miss a complete example for calling functions and using the returned values in a test.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Once I understood that everything must use or return the [type Value](http://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value), here is what I came up with.
The trick is to use:

- [`ValueOf`](http://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#ValueOf) in order to get a value of the receiver
- [`Value.MethodByName`](http://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.MethodByName) to find a function of that receiver *value*
- [`Value.IsNil`](http://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.IsNil) to test for `nil` returned value.

Main extract of the test code:

```go
var funcNames = []string{"Func1", "Func2", "Func3"}

func TestFunc(t *testing.T) {
    stype := reflect.ValueOf(s)
    for _, fname := range funcNames {

        fmt.Println(fname)

        sfunc := stype.MethodByName(fname)
        // no parameter => empty slice of Value
        ret := sfunc.Call([]reflect.Value{})

        val := ret[0].Int()

        // That would panic for a nil returned err
        // err := ret[1].Interface().(error)
                err := ret[1]

        if val < 1 {
            t.Error(fname + " should return positive value")
        }
        if err.IsNil() == false {
            t.Error(fname + " shouldn't err")
        }

    }
}
```

See a [runnable example in go playground](http://play.golang.org/p/9bZSozY6uH).

---

Note that if you are calling that test function with a non-existent function name, that will panic.
See [that example here](http://play.golang.org/p/_-DniPbsUC).

```go
runtime.panic(0x126660, 0x10533140)
    /tmp/sandbox/go/src/pkg/runtime/panic.c:266 +0xe0
testing.func·005()
    /tmp/sandbox/go/src/pkg/testing/testing.go:383 +0x180
----- stack segment boundary -----
runtime.panic(0x126660, 0x10533140)
    /tmp/sandbox/go/src/pkg/runtime/panic.c:248 +0x160
reflect.flag.mustBe(0x0, 0x13)
    /tmp/sandbox/go/src/pkg/reflect/value.go:249 +0xc0
reflect.Value.Call(0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0xfeef9f28, 0x0, ...)
    /tmp/sandbox/go/src/pkg/reflect/value.go:351 +0x40
main.TestFunc(0x10546120, 0xe)
    /tmpfs/gosandbox-3642d986_9569fcc1_f443bbfb_73e4528d_c874f1af/prog.go:34 +0x240
```

Go playground recover from that panic, but your test program might not.

That is why I added to the test function  above:

```go
for _, fname := range funcNames {

    defer func() {
        if x := recover(); x != nil {
            t.Error("TestFunc paniced for", fname, ": ", x)
        }
    }()
    fmt.Println(fname)
```

That produces ([see example](http://play.golang.org/p/S5YG1byEGv)) a much nicer output:

```go
Func1
Func2
Func3
Func4
--- FAIL: TestFunc (0.00 seconds)
    prog.go:48: Func2 should return positive value
    prog.go:51: Func3 shouldn't err
    prog.go:32: TestFunc paniced for Func4 :  reflect: call of reflect.Value.Call on zero Value
FAIL
```