# GO: find/scan for structs/functions

Tags: go

Is it possible in GO to find structs or functions by criteria such as name, tag or interface? i.e something along the lines of command line tasks/verbs? i.e:

```
func cmd1() {
    ...
}

func cmd2() {
    ...
}

...

func cmdN() {
}

func main() {
    // Inspect os.Args and call cmd{X}() based on args.
    ...
}
```

I don't mind what the exact mechanism is and if the final targets are functions or structs - the goal is to get something working by convention without any boilerplate code.

Comment: That reminds me of http://stackoverflow.com/a/20823837/6309

Comment: If you turn that into a minimal answer against the example above I'll accept it.

Comment: Sure, but in my case, those functions had a struct as a receiver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use reflection

```
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

var cmd command

type command struct{}

func (c command) execute(name string) {
    v := reflect.ValueOf(c)

    cmd := v.MethodByName(name)
    if !cmd.IsValid() {
        fmt.Println(name + " not a command")
        return
    }

    cmd.Call([]reflect.Value{})
}

func (c command) Cmd1() {
    fmt.Println("command 1")
}

func (c command) Cmd2() {
    fmt.Println("command 2")
}

func (c command) Cmd3() {
    fmt.Println("command 3")
}

func main() {
    flag.Parse()

    cmd.execute(flag.Arg(0))
}
```

or you could use a map.

```
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "fmt"
)

func cmd1() {
    fmt.Println("command 1")
}

func cmd2() {
    fmt.Println("command 2")
}

func cmd3() {
    fmt.Println("command 3")
}

var funcs = map[string]func(){
    "cmd1": cmd1,
    "cmd2": cmd2,
    "cmd3": cmd3,
}

func main() {
    flag.Parse()

    if f, ok := funcs[flag.Arg(0)]; ok {
        f()
    } else {
        fmt.Println(flag.Arg(0) + " command not found")
    }
}
```

Comment: The idea is to get a by-convention idiom and not have to manually maintain such a list, which in my particular case will grow to around ~500 items.

Comment: Unfortunately this is the only way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I used a similar approach in "[How to test a collection of functions by reflection in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20823837/6309)"

The idea is to list and find all the functions needed, in my case, functions for a certain struct type:

```
stype := reflect.ValueOf(s)
for _, fname := range funcNames {
    sfunc := stype.MethodByName(fname)
    // no parameter => empty slice of Value
    ret := sfunc.Call([]reflect.Value{})
```

Comment: Sorry - just realised your solution also requires knowing the methods up front. Basically this isn't doable in Go... https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/M0ORoEU115o